# Save previous cell VALUES and not only the last one (modify my code)

Tags: excel, vba

I found this interesting code that is almost perfect for my needs.
When a cell changes value, this code save the old value in another cell.

The problem is that when I change it again, it overwrite the previous "old value". So, at the end, I only have my "N value" and my "N-1 value".

What should I do to keep all the previous values? 
Let's say that I'm modifying the cell A1, the old value goes to B1.
I thought about a CONCATENATE function, save the B1 somewhere else, but I feel I'm going in a wrong way.

Thank you so much for your patience and time.

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xChangeRg As Range
Dim xDependRg As Range
Dim xDic As New Dictionary

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xDCell As Range
    Dim xHeader As String
    Dim xCommText As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    xHeader = "Previous value :"
    x = xDic.Keys

    For I = 0 To UBound(xDic.Keys)
        Set xCell = Range(xDic.Keys(I))
        Set xDCell = Cells(xCell.Row, 7)
        xDCell.Value = ""
        xDCell.Value = xDic.Items(I)
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I, J As Long
    Dim xRgArea As Range

    On Error GoTo Label1

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set xDependRg = Target.Dependents

    If xDependRg Is Nothing Then GoTo Label1

    If Not xDependRg Is Nothing Then
        Set xDependRg = Intersect(xDependRg, Range("C:C"))
    End If

Label1:
    Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("C:C"))
    If (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (Not xDependRg Is Nothing) Then
        Set xChangeRg = Union(xRg, xDependRg)
    ElseIf (xRg Is Nothing) And (Not xDependRg Is Nothing) Then
        Set xChangeRg = xDependRg
    ElseIf (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xDependRg Is Nothing) Then
        Set xChangeRg = xRg
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    xDic.RemoveAll

    For I = 1 To xChangeRg.Areas.Count
        Set xRgArea = xChangeRg.Areas(I)
        For J = 1 To xRgArea.Count
            xDic.Add xRgArea(J).Address, xRgArea(J).Formula
        Next
    Next

    Set xChangeRg = Nothing
    Set xRg = Nothing
    Set xDependRg = Nothing

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Lets say if you are replacing cell A1, and want the A1s old value to combine with cell B1; you can add A1s value to B1s value. Using a basic line of code like `Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value & ", " & Range("A1") .Value`

Comment: Thanks! But the code that I found can be easly applyed to a Range (Range("C:C")).
What should I add to make it work for that range?
Range("C:C").Value = Range("B:B").Value & ", " & Range("C:C") .Value ?
If yes, where should I add this line in the code?
Thanks again!

Comment: Up. Does anyone can help me please?